# Does my laptop have Ubuntu- compatibility issues?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, hp

I have bough a new hp notebook and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it.

It has Intel core i5 8th gen processor and 8 gb of ram.

However Ubuntu is somewhat laggy. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Tabbing between terminal, VSCode and chrome are not instant as i would expect them to be.

I think since the computer was shipped with pre-installed windows OS, i need to update my drivers as they are not compatible with Ubuntu? Has anyone experiences similar issues with installing Ubuntu on an hp laptop, and can point me in the direction of a tutorial/article to get my device compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: To the close voter's OP is not looking for shopping advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drivers probably aren't the problem. When you install Ubuntu, it installs the correct drivers for your system automatically. Having Ubuntu Dual-booted with Windows wouldn't affect drivers or driver compatibility. You could try changing the Ubuntu window manager  to reduce the lag when switching between windows. I would recommend wiping the hard drive of any computer that came with Windows pre-installed before installing a GNU/Linux distribution to free up space and for other various reasons. If you want to keep Microsoft Windows on the computer, then go ahead, but you will have less space with two different operating systems on one hard drive.

Comment: i have installed only Ubuntu, and deleted Windows. From what i can see of my 256gb SSD only the 18.04 OS is taking up space. It is not just the windows, Ubuntu itself is just laggy, its not performing well.

Comment: So you wiped the SSD and reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: If you did a complete wipe of the SSD and reinstalled Ubuntu and you are still experiencing lag and other problems, you could try changing the Ubuntu window manager. Other than that, I don't see any other reasons why you would be having these issues. It could be that when you install Ubuntu, it can't find any decent, open-source graphics drivers, so it just gave you the best open source driver it could find. When you are installing from a live media, you should be able to specify that you want to install 3rd party software. This might make it install the correct , functioning drivers.

Answer (score 2):

The delay when pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> seems to be a feature in gnome and can be removed by installing the [Alt-Tab Switcher Popup Delay Removal](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1317/alt-tab-switcher-popup-delay-removal/) gnome extension.

First, install the `gnome-tweak-tool` if you haven't already done so. From the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Next, launch `ubuntu software` by pressing <kbd>super</kbd> (or click `show applications`, by default it's in the bottom left corner under the favorites) and typing `ubuntu software`. Once launched, type `Alt-Tab Switcher Popup Delay Removal` and select `install`.

Lastly run `tweaks` (again using <kbd>super</kbd>), navigate to the `Extensions`-section and verify that the newly installed extension is set to `on`.